# How to loop TextView and PlainText?

Tags: android

I am editing the text view and plain text in the xml file always, when the new options comes in HashMAp. But, I am supposed to give the new options or more number of options in Hashmap and that should automatically change the new options in interface.

For example here there are three options in the map

gateway_ip: 162.198.23.10

net_mask: 178.465.37.34

server_ip: 243.798.76.59

I should be able to add more options or edit options in the HashMap and that should be automatically updated in the interface like this.

gateway_ip: 162.198.23.10

net_mask: 178.465.37.34

server_ip: 243.798.76.59

URL:  345.678.456.34

ip :  901.234.123.45

Basically I should change in hashmap that should update in interface automatically. Can anyone help me here ?

[Interface image][1]

/*-------------------------MainActivity.java--------------------------*/

```
package com.puchagmail.ganesh.trail2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;

import static android.R.attr.data;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView gateWay ;
TextView netMask;
TextView serverIp;

EditText gW;
EditText nM;
EditText sIp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gateWay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    netMask = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    serverIp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    gW = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText );
    nM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    sIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3 );
    setValues(dummyValues());
}


    public void setValues(HashMap<String,String>data){

    gW.setText(data.get("gateway_ip"));
    nM.setText(data.get("net_mask"));
    sIp.setText(data.get("server_ip"));


}

public HashMap<String,String> dummyValues(){
    HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();

    data.put("gateway_ip","162.198.23.10");
    data.put("net_mask","178.465.37.34");
    data.put("server_ip","243.798.76.59");
    return data;
}


}
```

/*---------activity_main.xml----------*/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.puchagmail.ganesh.trail2.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="66dp"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:text="net_mask"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="77dp"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
    android:text="gateway_ip"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="67dp"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:text="server_ip"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="192.168.85.100"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="254.100.34.567"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.078" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="465.798.86.345"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use android two way data binding using which you can achieve following things.

1) If you will change in hashmap manually then UI will automatically update.
2) If will enter any thing in edit text that will update in hashmap and on UI as well.

so you may learn about data binding using following link.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Comment: Now, I am able to edit only the plain text  but how can I add more number of options in Hashmap manually.